# How to download file from Sanity via HTTP?

Tags: sanity

I would like to know if there is possibility to download file from Sanity with HTTP request?

I only have reference ID:

```
{
   file: {
      asset: {
       _ref: "file-fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xlsx"
       _type: "reference"
       }    
    }
}
```

I would like to do this is this scenario:

```
<a href="https://cdn.sanity.io/assets/clientID/dataset/file-xxxxxxxxxxx-xlsx"> 
Download File 
</a>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can, indeed  With a bit of custom code you can do it just from the `_ref`, which is the file document's `_id`

### Creating the URL from the `_ref`/`_id` of the file

The `_ref`/`_id` structure is something like this: `file-{ID}-{EXTENSION}` (example: `file-207fd9951e759130053d37cf0a558ffe84ddd1c9-mp3`).

With this, you can generate the downloadable URL, which has the following structure: `https://cdn.sanity.io/files/{PROJECT_ID}/{DATASET}/{ID_OF_FILE}.{EXTENSION}`. Here's some pseudo Javascript code for the operation:

```js
const getUrlFromId = ref => {
  // Example ref: file-207fd9951e759130053d37cf0a558ffe84ddd1c9-mp3
  // We don't need the first part, unless we're using the same function for files and images
  const [_file, id, extension] = ref.split('-');
  return `https://cdn.sanity.io/files/${PROJECT_ID}/${DATASET}/${id}.${extension}`
}
```

### Querying the URL directly

However, if you can query for the file's document with [GROQ](https://www.sanity.io/docs/query-cheat-sheet) that'd be easier:

```
*[(YOUR FILTER HERE)] {
  file->{ url } // gets the URL from the referenced file
}
```

You can do the same with images, too.

Comment: Right.. I figured it out after some time. Thanks a lot